Is there an explicit formula for a recursion in an exponent
I'm trying to find an explicit form of $f(n) = 2^{f(n-1)} + f(n-1)$.
Everything I've been able to find handles linearly increasing exponents. I've had no luck finding any examples where the exponent itself uses the previous term. Does an explicit form for something like this exist?

That is https://oeis.org/A034797

Short answer: no.
Slightly longer answer: it depends on what functions you admit in your explicit forms in the first place. At one point in history exponents were invented because there was no explicit form for repeated multiplication yet. But if we agree that explicit forms include finite well-formed combinations of the variable $n,$ rational constants, the four basic operations of arithmetic, nested brackets and exponentiation, then no such form is available because no function thus constructed on the natural numbers increases sufficiently rapidly.
